# How do I get relevant information from a JSON output?

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file into JSON. While I am able to parse successfully using a HashMap, the XML file I am using has a lot of irrelevant information which also gets reflected in the JSON.

My XML file is a topology file, basically topology for network elements and their respective processes. So, it is divided into parent and child nodes. Most of the relevant information I seek lie with the parent nodes and I want to disregard the child nodes by whatever means, so that only the parent nodes are available in the JSON.

Here's the code I wrote to parse. I have tried to write code to get child `enter code here`nodes but I can't figure out how to remove them(like what conditions I can use):

```
static String nodeType1,nodeType;
    static String nodeName1,nodeName;
    static String nodeIP1,nodeIP;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try { File fXmlFile = new File("SystemTopology.txt");
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = 
          DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

          NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("SNOSNE") ;
          Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

          for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
              Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

              Element el = (Element) nNode;

              nodeType = el.getAttribute("snostype");
              nodeName = el.getAttribute("cimname");
              nodeIP = el.getAttribute("snoshostip");

              NodeList list = el.getChildNodes();

          for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
                  Node nNode1 = list.item(i);
           if(list.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
             Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
             nodeType1 = element.getAttribute("snostype");
             nodeName1 = element.getAttribute("cimname");
         nodeIP1 = element.getAttribute("snoshostip");
                if(!nodeIP1.isEmpty()) {
                      System.out.println(nodeType1);
                      System.out.println(nodeName1);
                      System.out.println(nodeIP1);
                        }
                  } 
              }
         //Need to add conditions here that would get only child nodes    
                  if(!nodeIP.isEmpty()) {
                      data.put(nodeName, nodeType+","+nodeIP);
                  }
          }
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
          System.out.printf( "JSON: %s", json.toString(2));
    }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {
          System.out.println("topology file not found " + excp.getMessage());
        }
```

Topology file looks like:

```
    <SNOSNE cimname="EDA_01" snoshostip="1.1.1.1" snostype="EDA">
         <SNOSNE cimname="Resources" snoshostip="1.1.1.1" snostype="EDA">
         </SNOSNE>
         <SNOSNE cimname="CPU" snoshostip="1.1.1.1" snostype="EDA">
         </SNOSNE>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </SNOSNE>
```

Expected output needs to contain only the parent with cimname="EDA_01". And all child nodes need to be disregarded in JSON output.

Comment: You could use XPath and/or XSLT to filter out the element(s) you are interested in, in XSLT 3 (as supported for Java by the open-source Saxon 9.8 and 9.9 HE) you can even directly construct JSON (see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2i where `array { //SNOSNE[@cimname = 'EDA_01']!map { @cimname : @snostype || ',' || @snoshostip } }` is pure XPath 3.1 used within XQuery 3.1 only to be able to define the right serialization. You might need to explain a bit more how your XML looks and which JSON you want to create.

Comment: Actually, the only thing I need to do is to figure out a condition which will be applied on the snoshostip to make it such that if it occurs once in parent node, it should skip the child nodes because they would have the same snoshostip as the parent. I have tried putting the key of the hashmap as the snoshostip but that scans through the XML and gives the last instance of the snoshostip in JSON. I want the opposite, if the snoshostip is found on parent, it skips the child nodes and go on to the next parent.

Comment: XPath (even version 1.0) can express your requirement as e.g. `//SNOSNE[@snoshostip and not ancestor::SNOSNE/@snoshostip]` so using XPath can help you navigate only to those elements you are looking for.